# Does adding a random number to my data make it secure?

Tags: randomness, secret-sharing

Say I have some real valued data that i want to keep secure. Now I have to pass on some modified version of the data to a second party for some computation, but i do not wish to reveal my data to the other party. If I add a value generated by a pseudo-random generating function to my data and then pass it on, does my data stay secure?

Comment: Who are you trying to secure your data against? Eavesdroppers or the other party?  Is your data already encrypted? How would adding an additional random value help?  If you're concerned about the other party, how could they possibly operate and perform calculations on mangled data?

Comment: @Kritner If F is the function the third party provides and E is some transformation applied to the input by the sender, then if F and E commute we have that E^-1(F(E(x))) = F(x), so that you can send E(x) to the third party and still make them indirectly compute F(x). Of course, useful choices of E are severely limited by what F does, but they do sometimes exist...

Comment: Note that there is a field called *homomorphic encryption* which does exactly what you are asking for. However, it generally requires both sides to implement the scheme, and not all calculations may be possible (fully homomorphic encryption schemes exist, but they may not be effective enough for general use). Note also that *modular addition* may be fully secure, even given that the input is not well distributed; it might however be tricky to reverse the modular addition given the output of the function.

Comment: @Thomas I think I got what you're saying, I meant my comment more for the (at least I interpreted) ambiguous nature of the question.  "some computation" could be interpreted as performing analytics on data, which I would think actually require the data, vs validating through computation that some data is correct/accurate.

Comment: As well as [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) this question is also related to [differential privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy), although that topic might go above and beyond this specific example. Anyway, here is [an introduction](https://github.com/frankmcsherry/blog/blob/master/posts/2016-02-03.md) if you are interested.

Comment: yeah  here by operations i mean addition and multiplication that is applicable for homomorphic encryption schemes.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, adding a secret random value $r$ to secret data $s$ and publishing the result $t=r+s$ can leave $s$ confidential; not perfectly so, but arbitrarily close to perfectly.

How much information leaks about $s$ from revealing $t$ depends on the assumed distribution of $r$ and $s$. For example, if $s$ is assumed to be chosen in $\{0,1\}$, and we chose $r$ uniformly randomly in $\{0,\;1,\dots,\;2^{128}-3,\;2^{128}-2\}$, then $t$ fits a 128-bit bitstring. It $t$ is $0$ or $2^{128}-1$, then the adversary has learned $s$ with certainty, but that's unlikely: probability about (just above) $2^{-127}$ for any distribution of $s$, or about $2^{-128}$ if $s$ is chosen by fair coin toss. And in other cases, the adversary has learned nothing about $s$.

More generally, if $s$ is an $m$-bit integer and $r$ is a uniformly random $n$-bit integer, then probability that the adversary learns anything about $s$ from $t$ is at worst about $2^{n-m-1}$ when that's small.

Other distributions of $r$ allow $t$ to use much less bits, without increasing the probability that an adversary learns $s$ with sizable probability, but trade this against more often revealing a little about $s$.

---

The question mentions that it should still be possible to perform some computation about $s$ from the masked $t$. That holds for addition at least. For example we can perform $t_i=s_i+r_i$ for several secret $s_i$, and the $r_i$ generated pseudo-randomly from a key $K$ and $i$ (using some [PRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) such as [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)). $\sum t_i$ then allows to find $\sum s_i$ for one knowing $K$.

Comment: I think that Riddhi is wishing to allow the data to be computed upon by the other party, not encrypted per se. _"i do not wish to reveal my data to the other party."_ I've just discarded my answer when I re-read the question.